# Getting data file and log file free space size during database restoring

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding SQL Server databases.

I'm trying to get the data file and log file free space size when the database is in a restoring state.

I've tried a few methods (e.g. `FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed')`), but none of them seem to be working. Can anyone suggest a solution or give me some guidance on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible - metadata inside the database is inaccessible while the database is in recovery. Even the performance counters don't show anything useful in this state, e.g. these always return 0 (along with every other counter relating to the transaction log):

```
SELECT counter_name, cntr_value
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
  WHERE instance_name = 'your database'
  AND counter_name IN 
    ('Log File(s) Size (KB)', 'Log File(s) Used Size (KB)');
```

The data file size (`Data File(s) Size (KB)`) seems to be accurate here, but size alone doesn't help. You can get the data and log file sizes from `master.sys.master_files`, but this catalog view doesn't know anything about space used / space free, so really it doesn't tell you anything more than looking in File Explorer.

If you want this information without fully restoring on *this* system, you'll have to test restoring the same backup `WITH RECOVERY` on another system.